# Word Command Button Close Document

Tags: forms, vba, ms-word, command

I have a script that emails a completed form to me but I need it to close the form once the user clicks on the submit button.

Here is the script I have for the email portion, but what do I change to make it close once submitted?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object
Dim Doc             As Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = "Privacy Information Questionaire"
    .Body = "Privacy Information Questionaire" & vbCrLf & _
    "Body Line 2" & vbCrLf & _
    "Body Line 3"
    .To = "email@example.com"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImprotanceHigh Or olImprotanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the current document, you can insert this at the end of your code:

```
Application.ActiveDocument.Close
```

To ensure that all Word windows are closed, you can use

```
Application.Quit
```

Be warned, though, that this will close other non-related documents and (depending on your other code and settings) may not prompt the user to save changes.